# Opencart store admin not working

Tags: php, mysql, html, admin, opencart

I accidentally deleted all my hosted files. Luckily I had a backup but the admin does not seem to work still:

http://zabb.co.uk/store/upload/admin/

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: as the error explains, there is a missing object and this object has the isLogged() method that you are trying to access..it looks like you haven't backed up all your files or maybe you forgot to load this object into your code

Answer (score 1):

You need to upload all files as they are in the exact same structure. Note you *shouldn't* have the `upload` folder up there, only the files and folders in it. Also, make sure your `system` folder is in the right place, as without that you won't have the `customer.php` file in `system/library/`